# What happens if DepthBias is set to very large?

Tags: directx

Coming from the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc308048(v=vs.85).aspx) if we set the DepthBias to be very large, will it be also be drawn further from the vertices and will be visible?

Comment: DepthBias only impacts depth-testing. It's typically used to make 'decal' textures that are drawn co-incident with drawn geometry visible despite having the same calculate z-value in the depth buffer. If you make the depth-bias very large, it's likely to be beyond all existing z-values in the -depth buffer. The result depends on what depth-test comparison function you have enabled.

Comment: Great. So the DepthBias should be in accordance to keep the value below 1 and greater than 0 if DirectX is under consideration.